# Monit Apache2 restart and Apache status

Tags: server, apache2, monit

I am practicing using linux/Ubuntu.

I have installed apache2 on my cloud server (Lightsail). I have also installed Monit to monitor Apache2. The monitoring is working correctly and Monit restarts Apache2 when it's down (I did sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop to test it). The IP (in browser) went unavailable and then came back online.

The issue I am facing is that when Monit restarts apache the sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status shows the service as down, but apache is running (IP checked on browser).

```
ubuntu@webserver:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-04-27 22:21:17 UTC; 2min 51s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22026 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20709 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21958 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 125ms


Apr 27 22:17:25 webserver systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Apr 27 22:17:25 webserver apache2[21958]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 27 22:17:26 webserver apache2[21958]:  *
Apr 27 22:17:26 webserver systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 27 22:21:17 webserver systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Apache2 web server...
Apr 27 22:21:17 webserver apache2[22026]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 27 22:21:17 webserver apache2[22026]:  *
Apr 27 22:21:17 webserver systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

This is what sudo vim /etc/monit/monitrc has:

```
check process apache2 with pidfile /run/apache2/apache2.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" with timeout 15 seconds
    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
```

How do I make sure that Apache2 is restarted correctly so that sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status shows the correct status?

**Edit 1:**
My /etc/monit/monitrc looks like this:

```
  set daemon 60
  set logfile /var/log/monit.log
  set idfile /var/lib/monit/id
  set statefile /var/lib/monit/state
set mailserver localhost
  set eventqueue
      basedir /var/lib/monit/events
      slots 100

set alert first-email@gmail.com
set alert second-email@domain-name.com

set httpd port 2812 and
    use address localhost
    allow localhost
    allow admin:monit

check process apache2 with pidfile /run/apache2/apache2.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"

check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start" with timeout 60 seconds
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the monit code to the following fixed the issue:

```
check process apache2 with pidfile /run/apache2/apache2.pid
    start program = "/bin/systemctl start apache2.service" with timeout 15 seconds
    stop program  = "/bin/systemctl stop apache2.service"
    restart program = "/bin/systemctl restart apache2.service"
```